# Two Realtime DataSets in One Chart - MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am constantly reading data from USB, and want to represent it on two LineDataSets in One Linechart on an Android App, using the library MPAndroidChart (really great btw).
 My problems are two, but the same:

1. When I try add more than one `LineDataSet` on a `List<ILineDataSet>` and show it, the two linesDataSets don't always appear together (sometimes just one is shown, and later it dissapear and the other one is shown).
2. At the same moment, (I really don't know how is possible) the `LineDataSet` it are exchanging with each other: Line1 is with the Line2's data and vice versa, and constantly alternating this way.

Why this is happening?
Can anyone tell me how I solve it or at least a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: There is not enough info here to diagnose the problem. Please try and make a [mcve]. The data in one DataSet interfering with the other sounds like a problem due to misuse of the `static` keyword but need more info.

Comment: Sorry. I realized what my problem was, after a lot of research. It was in another part of the application, mixed with an error on the hardware I am using. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized what my problem was, after a lot of research. It was in another part of the application, mixed with an error on the hardware I am using.

**It has nothing to do with MPAndroidChart Library.** It is excelent! The problem was dragged from another module.
Sorry and thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with MPAndroidChart Library. It is excelent! The problem was dragged from another module.